# XSD extension with additional attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

I am using an extension of a type and I am trying to add another attribute that needs to be of a specific type. Sadly I can only get one of them to work at a time.

Code example (this is just the current state of many things I tried):

```
<xs:complexType name="buttonBaseType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:attribute name="text" type="nonEmptyString"/>
        <xs:extension base="elementCommonInfo"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

`elementCommonInfo` defines some attributes, lets say 2, one that has a default value and one that does not have such a thing.

So in this version the following code `<button text="e"/>` creates the error `base-frame.xml:7:27: attribute 'text' is not declared for element 'button'`. If I move the `xs:attribute` from the `xs:complexType` one level higher (before or after `xs:complexType`) the document passes validation, even though there are attributes from `elementCommonInfo` that have to be there that are not present.

TL;DR: How do I get all the attributes from the extension together with new attributes I am defining in the "extending" type?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try it in this way:

```
<xs:complexType name="buttonBaseType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="elementCommonInfo">
            <xs:attribute name="text" type="nonEmptyString"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: provided that `elementCommonInfo` has a simple type.